# Checking if a string holds an Integer

Tags: parsing, haskell

Why this code doesn't work:

```
import IO
import Char

isInteger "" = False
isInteger (a:b) =
  if length b == 0 && isDigit(a) == True then True
  else if isDigit(a) == True then isInteger(b)
  else False

main = do
    q <- getLine
    let x = read q
    if isInteger x == False then putStrLn "not integer"
    else putStrLn "integer"
```

Comment: `isInteger s = not (null s) && all isDigit s`  :-)

Comment: Also note that `x == True` is the same thing as `x`.  `(== True)` is the identity function.  So eg. the first line could be `if length b == 0 && isDigit a then True`.  But... you are still working way too hard :-)

Comment: @luqui why is `not (null s)` necessary?

Comment: @Rein, because `all isDigit ""` is vacuously true, but it isn't an integer (`read` will not parse it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a string and testing if it is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084013/reading-a-string-and-testing-if-it-is-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
main = do
    q <- getLine -- q is already String - we don't need to parse it
    if isInteger q == False then putStrLn "not integer"
    else putStrLn "integer"
```

The reason for your code results in runtime error "Prelude.read: no parse" is that since `getLine :: IO String` and `isInteger :: String -> Bool`, the expression `let x = read x` will try to parse `String` into `String`. Try it yourself:

```
Prelude> read "42" :: String
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

PS It's not that you can't parse String (although it's still doesn't really make sense to do that), you can, but the input should be different: `String` is just a list of `Char` and even though `Show` threats `[Char]` as a special case `Read` doesn't, so in order to `read` `String` just pass it as a list:

```
Prelude> read "['4','2']" :: String
"42"
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps us if you give us the error message:

```
/home/dave/tmp/so.hs:14:4:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Line 14 is `else putStrLn "integer"`

The hint that this is to do with indentation is correct. When you use if-then-else with do-notation, you need to ensure that multiline expressions --- and if-then-else is a single expression --- have extra indentation after the first line.

(You do not use do-notation in your `isInteger` function, which is why the same indentation of if-then-else does not cause problems there.)

So this has no compile errors:

```
main = do
    q <- getLine
    let x = read q
    if isInteger x == False then putStrLn "not integer"
     else putStrLn "integer"
```

Neither does this:

```
main = do
    q <- getLine
    let x = read q
    if isInteger x == False
      then putStrLn "not integer"
      else putStrLn "integer"
```

You then still have the issue Ed'ka points out. But at least it compiles.

Comment: It hurts the eye: `if something == False then B else A`. Better: `if something then A else B`.

Comment: Or at least use `not` instead of `== False`