# Reading a string and testing if it is a number

Tags: parsing, haskell, io

Why this code doesn't work ? I would like to return Bool if string is a number.

```
isNumber = do
    n <- getLine
    let val = case reads n of
                ((v,_):_) -> True
                _ -> False
```

Comment: If you have not read it yet, here's a link to a very good Haskell tutorial: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Answer (score 16):

Firstly, you have a syntax error:

```
A.hs:3:5:
    The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression:
    let val
          = case reads n of {
              ((v, _) : _) -> True
              _ -> False }
```

Because your function doesn't return a value yet. Fixing that:

```
isNumber = do
    n <- getLine
    let val = case reads n of
                ((v,_):_) -> True
                _         -> False
    return val
```

Now it is syntactically correct, but it has a type error:

```
A.hs:3:20:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Read a0) arising from a use of `reads'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Why? Because `read` is overloaded. So the compiler doesn't know *what* you're trying to read. In this case, you're trying to read a number. Let's say, an `Integer`:

```
isNumber :: IO Bool
isNumber = do
    n <- getLine
    let val = case (reads :: ReadS Integer) n of
                ((v,_):_) -> True
                _         -> False
    return val
```

Still, its not really idiomatic. Let's separate the IO from the pure code, and actually return the parsed number, if it succeeds:

```
readNumber :: String -> Maybe Integer
readNumber s = case reads s of
            ((v,_):_) -> Just v
            _         -> Nothing

getNumber :: IO (Maybe Integer)
getNumber = do
    s <- getLine
    return (readNumber s)
```

Testing:

```
*Main> getNumber 
123
Just 123
*Main> getNumber 
dons
Nothing
```

So we've cleaned up the parsing, and separted IO from parsing, meaning you can test your parser in isolation, and added type information to document your design.

Comment: I would like to get True or False and Your code unfortunatelly returns me number or Nothing.

Comment: You can convert a `Maybe` to a `Bool` by using the `isJust` function. E.g. `isJust <$> getNumber`.

Comment: So I need 3 functions: readNumber, getNumber and isJust - too many functions - I need only one - so I need other solution.

Comment: The point of my post was to show you how to decompose the problem into its three parts, and you can then combine them into one function that does the job *properly*. Your single function is just the *composition* of those three, independent functions: `getLine`, `readNumber` and `isJust`. Building up code piecewise like this is just good development practice.

Comment: But if for some reason you don't want to do it idiomatically, the last version of `isNumber` does in fact do exactly what you want. It's just ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return val` or simply write `return $ case ...`. The last statement in `do ...` must be an expression. In your particular case it must be an expression of type `IO Bool`, so you need to lift value into IO monad with `return` function. You also need to specify type for `v` explicitly (you will probably need `ScopedTypeVariables` GHC extension for this.)

It is also a good idea to write a separate pure function of type `String -> Bool` and use it in the impure IO code.